# Graph API get profile image from Comment object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As the Graph API documentation says, the /comment retreives a Comment Object, which contains a from attribute, which represents the user that made the comment. By default, that from attribute comes with an id and a name.

Although I know I can get the profile image with the id, it will depend on the access_token as the way would be like this:

```
return 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/picture?type=large&access_token=' + accessToken;
```

How can I do to get the profile img of the commentator without depending on the access_token? Because when the API retreives a User object, in the fields object, you can request `{ fields: "id,name,picture }`. But how can i do to ask for the picture to the from attribute that comes in the Comment object? As this is not allowed `{ fields: "id,name,from.picture }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to ask for second level attributes

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

```
$ fbapi '/v2.6/me/photos?fields=from{picture}' | jq '.data[0]'
{
  "from": {
    "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/xxxx/p50x50/xxxx.jpg",
    "id": "9999999999"
  },
  "id": "000000000"
}
```